# Writing in Sqlite

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want something like this :

```
   public String getDates(int id)
   {
    String query = ("SELECT  DIA FROM " + TABLE_NAME + "WHERE ID"  + "=\""  + id + "\"");
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
    String date = "";

    return date;
   }
```

And I want to assign date to the result from that query, how I do I get it ?

Comment: missing space: `TABLE_NAME + "WHERE ID"`

Comment: Change `execSQL()` (it's for **commands**, not **queries***) to `rawQuery()` (this is for **queries** = `SELECT`).

Comment: and then how do I assign it ?

Comment: use `Cursor` and `moveToFirst()` and `moveToNext()`

Comment: Can you write an answer? Should I use a cursor ?

Comment: @EmanuelSobreiro check my answer

Comment: @IntelliJ did that

Comment: Yes, you should. See @intellijamiya's answer. You need a (scrollable) container to store your records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String get_VALUE = "";
    String last_query = "SELECT DIA FROM " + TABLE_TESTES + " WHERE " + ID + " = '" + id+ "'";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(last_query, null);
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) 
    {
        get_VALUE = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("DIA"));
    }
    db.close();
    return get_VALUE;
```

Comment: I think DIA is name of column and should be in query string not as a variable.

Comment: @MehranZamani May be . I don't know .I just write code

Comment: how about id? if it is an integer, why put it between single quote?

Comment: @MehranZamani Indeed .

Comment: @MehranZamani If it is an integer you don't need **any** kind of quotes. Not `'`, as you pointed out, but also not `\"` (@amiya... please correct), as in your original query.

Comment: @Rotwang thanks, that was my point and also a loop can help with results more than one row.

Comment: Ty for your help! By that way im getting this error:                                                  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
 any ideas ?

Comment: Small improvement (just for readability): I'd change `get_VALUE = c.getString(0);` to `get_VALUE = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("DIA"));` I prefer to use column names. In particular, when I get more columns from a single query.

Comment: @EmanuelSobreiro That's now a different question.

Comment: Sure I will make it